# How to find in-sample sum-of-squared errors and $R^2$ after glm?

Tags: regression, r-squared

My formula is:

```
glm(formula = total ~ yr * mnth, data = daytots)
```

`yr` and `mnth` are factors, and `total` is numerical.

I want to find in-sample sum-of-squared errors and $R^2$ but it seems like the `glm()` function does not return both.

Does anyone know how to find them? Thanks!

Comment: Why use glm instead of lm? It looks like you’re not using a link function (so the identity link...linear regression).

Comment: Good point @Dave.  But the link isn't the relevant issue; what matters is the *conditional distribution* posited in the model.  When that distribution is a location-scale family (and the only such family supported in `glm` is the Gaussian) then analyzing additive "errors" makes sense.  Doing that analysis in terms of *squared* errors is particularly appropriate only for the Gaussian family.  It would still be appropriate even with a nonlinear link.

Comment: I meant the software issue that lm returns $R^2$ and I think SSE, while glm does not. It looks like the model is a regular linear model, which glm will fit but not return the linear-specific information like $R^2$. Or do you mean something more like a linear regression but where it’s an exponential distribution (for example) sliding up and down the regression line instead of a Gaussian?

Answer (score 1):

`glm` uses maximum likelihood estimation, and for this kind of model, r-squared is not defined.  However, there are various pseudo r-squared measures that may be helpful, even if they don't have the same interpretation as the r-squared for OLS linear models.

Below I calculate Efron's pseudo r-square for some toy data, which I think is pretty easy to understand.

A [good source on pseudo r-square measures is from UCLA's Institute for Digital Research and Education](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faq-what-are-pseudo-r-squareds/).

I'm not sure I know what you mean by "in-sample sum-of-squared errors", but it may be reasonable to calculate mean square error (*MSE*) and root mean square error (*RMSE*). These can be calculated from the predicted (*predy*) and observed (*actual*) values.

Source for the R code, with the caveat that I am the author of this function: https://rdrr.io/cran/rcompanion/man/accuracy.html

```
### Create toy data, linear model, and analysis of deviance.

yr    = as.factor(rep(c("1241", "1534", "1643"), each =5))
mnth  = as.factor(rep(c("Oct", "Nov", "Dec"), 5))
total = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)

daytots = data.frame(yr, mnth, total)

model = glm(formula = total ~ yr * mnth, data = daytots)

library(car)

Anova(model)

### Calculate Efron's r-square

actual = total
predy  = predict(model)

RSS = sum((actual - predy)^2)
Var = sum((actual - mean(actual))^2)

Effron = 1 - RSS/Var

Effron

   ### 0.904

### Calculate mean square error and rmse

actual = total
predy  = predict(model)

MSE = mean((actual - predy)^2)

MSE

   ### 1.8

RMSE = sqrt(MSE)

RMSE

   ### 1.34
```